# Read PDF (Acrobat Reader DC Only) to Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

Tryinf to read PDF data into excel using VBA Code. I only have access to Adobe Reader DC on the work machine.

I have tried the following code

```
Sub ReadAdobeFields()

 Dim AcrobatApplication As Acrobat.CAcroApp
 Dim ArcrobatDocument As Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc
 Dim fcount As Long

 Dim sFields As String

 On Error Resume Next

 Set AcrobatApplication = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
 Set AcrobatDocument = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

 If AcrobatDocument.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Summary.pdf", "") Then

      AcrobatApplication.Show
      Set AcroForm = CreateObject("AFormatAut.App")
      Set Fields = AcroForm.Fields
      fcount = Fields.Count

      For Each Field In Fields
       row_number = row_number + 1
       sFieldName = Field.Name

       Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number) = Field.Name
       Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number) = Field.Value
       Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number) = Field.Style

      Next Field

      Else

        MsgBox "Failure"


    End If

    AcrobatApplication.Exit
    Set Arcobat.Application = Nothing
    Set Acrobat.Document = Nothing
    Set Field = Nothing
    Set Fields = Nothing
    Set AcroForm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Expected outcome would be successfully reading the PDF file data and placing into excel format using VBA coding.

Comment: That's not possible with the Reader. `AcroExch.App` needs the full Adobe Acrobat. Actually reading a PDF into Excel will be a mess. You have to think of a PDF as a printed sheet of paper, there is no actual data structure like in an Excel worksheet.